# Setting Partitioning Function Before Loading Avro Files

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, partitioning

I have a large data set in Avro format which needs to be partitioned upon loading.  What I currently do is to first load the files and then call *repartition()* to organize the data to my requirements as shown in the following block:

```
val df = spark.load.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("/mypath")
val partitionedDF = df.repartition(count, col(id))
```

I was wondering if it is at all possible to change the default partitioner such that by the time I load the avro files no *repartition()* is needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The data will not actually be loaded in either of the lines of code you listed.  Because of spark's lazy evaluation, nothing will happen until you run an "action" (such as collect, write, take, etc).

If you want to improve the performance of the data load, you can split up the avro files before you load them in (aka partition the avro files by 'id' and have one file for each id).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  If I understand correctly, I could "pre-partition" the files by loading all the files and do something like this:

a) For each set of files, create one data frame.
b) Create a master data frame by calling _union()_ on all data frames.  The new data frame will have as many partitions as the sum of the original data frames.
c) The master data frame is partitioned already and I don't need to call _repartition()_

Please let me know if this is correct.